# mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW PACKAGE STATUS WHERE Db = when rake db:migrate finishes migration

Tags: mysql, docker, ruby-on-rails-5, aws-codebuild

I am running tests on Codebuild using Docker. I am using MySQL 5.7 community server using mysql docker image. In my dockerfile, I am using following apt-get update command to get `default-mysql-client`.

```
RUN apt-get install -qq -y build-essential locales nodejs software-properties-common ffmpeg pngquant procps vim default-mysql-client mycli tig httpie > /dev/null
```

But when migrations run and about to finish it raises error and terminates

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW PACKAGE STATUS WHERE Db = 'development'': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PACKAGE STATUS WHERE Db = 'development'' at line 1 (1064) 
rake aborted! 
failed to execute: `mysqldump` 
Please check the output above for any errors and make sure that `mysqldump` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.
```

It was working fine previously and just started since yesterday on Codebuild. Can anybody help regarding this ?

I think Codebuild has migrated to `buster debian` build and now 
`default-mysql-client` is fetching `mariadb-client-10.3` instead of `mariadb-client-10.1` and due to that this issue is getting raised.

Moreover, I have tried explicitly replacing `default-mysql-client` with `mariadb-client-10.1` but codebuild fails to find the package and that makes sense since `mariadb-client-10.1` is not available for `buster`.